# Missing questions on a DS-160 form

Tags: b1-b2-visas, united-airlines

What do I do if some of the questions on my form do not appear on my spouse's form? My spouse and I are applying/filling out DS-160 forms for our B2 visa. But I am amazed to notice that some of the questions on my form are missing on my spouse's form. Here they are:

1. ON THE TRAVEL INFORMATION SECTION

   - a. Have you made specific travel plans?
   - b. Provide a complete
     itinerary for your travel to the U.S.
   - c. Date of Arrival in U.S.:
   - d. Arrival City:
   - e. Date of Departure from U.S.:
   - f. Departure City:
   - g. the locations you wish to visit in the US
2. EDIT PREVIOUS WORK INFORMATION

   - Name of Institution (1):
   - Address of Institution:
   - City:
   - State/Province:
   - Postal Zone/ZIP Code:
   - Country/Region:
   - Course of Study:
   - Date of Attendance From:
   - Date of Attendance To:
   - Name of Institution (2):
   - Address of Institution:
   - City:
   - State/Province:
   - Postal Zone/ZIP Code:
   - Country/Region:
   - Course of Study:
   - Date of Attendance From:
   - Date of Attendance To:
3. ADDITIONAL INFORMATION

   - A. Do you belong to a clan or tribe?
   - B. Provide a List of Languages You Speak:
   - C. Have you traveled to any countries/regions within the last five years?
   - D. Provide a List of Countries/Regions Visited
   - E. Have you belonged to, contributed to, or worked for any professional, social, or charitable organization?
   - F. Do you have any specialized skills or training, such as firearms, explosives, nuclear, biological, or chemical experience?
   - G. Have you ever served in the military?
   - H. Have you ever served in, been a member of, or been involved with a paramilitary unit, vigilante unit, rebel group, guerrilla group, or insurgent organization?

Comment: @dda It really is  "B-2". Just about all US visas use the letter-number format.

Comment: But surely not B=2...

Answer (score 4):

The DS-160 form has extra questions for male applicants compared to the same form for female applicants.
In addition to all of the questions on the 'female' version of the form, male applicants are also asked questions about:

- educational institutions that they have attended
- trips that they have made in the last five years
- military service record

So what you're seeing is not unusual. Complete all of the questions which you are asked - more for you (male) than for your spouse (female).

Comment: Interesting. Is there any official explanation of why?

Comment: @krubo, The extra questions are actually from a different form, DS-157, though online they are just extra DS-160 questions. Males between 16 and 54 years old (i.e. "military age") are required to submit them.